# Image format conversion opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am doing a project and it needs to convert the image format. Firstly, I need to change the image from `cv::Mat` format to `Image<byte>` format which is a kind of black-white frame. The following code shows how to change from `cv::Mat` to `Image<byte>`.

```
void conversionNB(Mat frame, Image<byte> &imBW)
{ 
    Mat clone = frame.clone();
    Mat_<Vec3b>& frame_p = (Mat_<Vec3b>&)clone;
    for(int i = 0; i < 480; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 640; j++)
        {
            imBW[i][j] = (frame_p(i,j)[0] + frame_p(i,j)[1] + frame_p(i,j)[2])/3;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, after processing of the images, I need to change the images back to `cv::Mat` format to show them. Does someone know how to change from `Image<byte>` to `cv::Mat` according to the code?

P.S. `Image<byte>` is an 8-bit data type from cvd library.

```
namespace CVD
{
   typedef unsigned char byte;
}
```

Comment: Image<byte> is not from opencv, care to explain what it is ?

Comment: Image<byte> is an 8-bit data type from cvd library. typedef unsigned char byte

Comment: [this one](http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/cvd/html/image_8h_source.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To change from `Image<byte>` to `cv::Mat`

   Mat image(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,(unsigned char*)imBW.data());
   for a gray scale image.
2. your code might runs slow. we can create cvd image and opencv mat directly from unsigned char* data.

   void conversionNB(Mat& frame, Image &imBW){
       Mat cvd_image(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_8UC1,(unsigned char*)imBW.data());
       cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
       frame.copyTo(cvd_image);
   }

   void conversionRGB(Mat& frame, Image > &imRGB){
       Mat cvd_image(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_8UC3,(unsigned char*)imRGB.data());
       cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGB);
       frame.copyTo(cvd_image);
   }